# Probability that a top square has a multiple of 3 a square is the sum of the 2 squares below it.

Tags: combinatorics

A triangular tower is built with 11 rows as shown. Each square on the bottom row contains the number 0 or 1. Each square above the bottom row is the sum of the two squares below it. A student insists on the number in the top square being a multiple of 3. How many ways are there entering the 0s and 1s in the bottom row to satisfy the student?

[Triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8z8oL.png)

Firstly, we know that placing only $0$'s will end up with the sum $0$ (which is a multiple of 3). Placing only $1$'s will give us a final sum of $312$ (this is a multiple of $3$). I know that the maximum number we can end up with is $312$ and the minimum is $0$. Therefore, there are $208$ different multiples of $3$ between $0$ and $312$. This is what I have done so far.

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Please **edit the question** to provide this information.  This looks like an interesting question.  I’d hate to see it closed for lack of demonstrated effort.

Comment: 0 isn't a multiple of 3?

Comment: That was a mistake. Fixed now.

Comment: I also think your number at the top for all 1s in the bottom row is incorrect. It should be actually be 1024.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose the numbers in the bottom row are $a_0, a_2, \dots, a_{10}$. Then the number at the top (call it $S$) is:
$$
\begin{equation}
S = \sum_{i=0}^{10}a_i{10 \choose i}
\end{equation}
$$

Since $a_i$ is either 0 or 1, for this sum to be divisible by 3, $S \equiv 0\pmod 3$. That is,
$$
\begin{align}
a_0 + a_1 + a_{10} + a_{11} \equiv 0 \pmod 3
\end{align}
$$
We obtain the above by observing that
$$
{10 \choose i} \equiv \begin{cases}
1 \pmod 3,\, i = 0, 1, 10, 11 \\
0 \pmod 3,\, \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

The sum is congruent to $0$ either when all the $4$ numbers are $0$ or when $3$ of them are $1$ and the other one is $0$. So, the required probability is
$$
\frac{1 \text{} + {4 \choose 3}}{2^4} = 5/16
$$

Comment: I don't understand how the sum of all the bottom squares equals the top square. Say that the bottom squares are all 1, the sum would be 11. However, we know that the top square must be 1024. Could you please explain this a bit further?

Comment: @luezoid The formula in my answer (first expression for $S$) also gives 1024.